# Play! framework dependency management

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.2

I have Play! 2.2.1 Eclipse project and I have problem with dependencies.
I try to add dependency in Build.scala file 
        `"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.8.0"`, and it is resolved when I run `play` in project directory and it is shown when i run command `dependencies`. However, I am unable to use it in my project and it is not in `Eclipse build path`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: most probably you need to `clean` and `eclipse` your app again.

Comment: That was the case! Thanks!